# Create DataFrame having trouble

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, integer

I'm trying to convert views_dict[2017] to a dataframe. Using jupyter notebook. If I use variable of views_dict I have numerous years in dictionary format.

views_dict[2017]

[2102206,
1331781,
925375,
382331,
321960,
278439,
231613,
206570,
179082,
173855,
137089,
123836,
122077,
120140,
114837,
108279,
103176,
93963,
79388,
72907]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(views_dict)), columns = ['views'])
df

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [27], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(views_dict)), columns = ['views'])
2 df

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: you have to run this cell again `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.